# Windows 7 & Open Suse 13.1

Tags: grub

I have Windows 7 on my laptop. I installed opensuse 13.1 and after installing opensuse 13.1 Windows boot loader is replaced by grub 2.

I could not understand opensuse 13.1 as it is not user friendly and I could not understand it and I want to format it

For this purpose first of all I have to restore my Windows 7 boot loader. So how can restore my Windows boot loader over grub 2. How can I format opensuse 13.1 from Windows 7
Please guide me thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

OMG, just type fdisk /mbr in a DOS-window:

Fdisk has an undocumented parameter called /mbr that causes it to write the master boot record to the hard disk without altering the partition table information.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Windows 7 DVD to run `Startup repair` - this will repair your bootloader and Windows 7 will boot as normal.